# angular replace panel in the same spot

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular js app as in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YGP1jKsWl6g6V6REeTRu)

When the **+** next to the `My academic course` is clicked, it opens a new panel to get a list of courses to select from. Here when we click 'Academic' it shows a new panel with all its children. But when i click Associate in `Applied Sciences`, it opens a new panel next to the previous instead of replacing the previous panel. How can i define a way to replace the 'Academic' panel with the 'Applied Sciences' panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [updated your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JJXE5v8FJxSBv1fjIeKF?p=preview) to show you one way this could be done.

Basically, you run a function in your `ng-click` on the "academic" and "appliedscience" buttons. In this function you can make a simple *toggle* to switch between the two alternatives. If you want more buttons, just add it to the *toggle*.

Comment: hi one more question. Can we make the panel to go away when we reclick on the same button ie. when i click 'academic', it brings the academic panel. when i click on the 'academic' again, i want the panel to go away.

Comment: hi i just posted a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225867/angular-pass-arguments-to-ng-show-to-connect-to-different-jsons