# Angular pass arguments to ng-show to connect to different jsons

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following angular js app: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YLTN0rt9OQMe4E11EkU8?p=preview)

When the **+** next to the `My academic course` is clicked, it opens a new panel to get a list of courses to select from. Here when we click 'Academic' it shows a new panel with all its children and similarly even for the 'Applied Sciences'.

What i am trying to achieve here is, when we click on any item from the list inside the **'Academic'** or **'Applied Sciences'** panel, i want it to connect to the `$scope.degreecategories` and return all the `'Degree'` names from that json where the **DegreeCategoryID** in this json matches to the **DegreeCategoryID** in `$scope.degrees` json.

I tried something very weird but am sure am not in the right track. Any ideas on how to pass the arguments to the `ng-show`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/9RdNNosu7W8b5jXrmJ2J?p=preview).

In the `li`element i changed you `ng-click` to pass in the object.

```
<li ng-click="display.showSelectedCourse(degree)" >{{degree.DegreeCategory}}</li>
```

I added a table (just to show you the filtered result) with a simple filter function. The table uses an ng-repeater.

Filter function

```
$scope.showOnlyCat = function(cat) {
    return (cat.DegreeCategoryID == $scope.display.theSelectedCourse.DegreeCategoryID);
}
```

The filter is used like this in the markup:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="cat in degreecategories | filter:showOnlyCat">
     <td>{{...showing data ....}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```